# Finding a strict Lyapunov function for a system of ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

Regarding this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2839802/628464), of the following system :
$$\begin{cases}
\dot x=y-x^2-x \\\
\dot y=3x-x^2-y \\ 
\end{cases}$$
how can I prove that the equilibrium point $(1,2)$ is asymptotically stable using 
a Lyapunov function.
I chose my Lyapunov function to be $V(x,y) = a(x-1)^2 + b(y-2)^2 $,
and with change of variables: $x=u+1 ,\\ y=v+2$
$\Rightarrow V(u,v) = au^2 + bv^2 $ and $\dot V=-2au^3-6au^2+2auv+2buv-2bu^2v-2bv^2$  
 But I can't determine what $a ,b$ should be in order to receive a  strict Lyapunov function.
Would appreciate any help.
Thanks:)

Comment: First, if you have already chosen your Lyapunov function to be something, why the change of variable? Second, I'm not sure where $a$ and $b$ come from after the change of variable.

Comment: I thought maybe the change of variable would help me to understand what my parameters should be, but it didn't get me anywhere..

Comment: I would suggest to firstly draw phase portrait and see whether the point is actually stable and then try to find Lyapunov function. If not do not waste your energy.

Comment: Seemingly the point is not globally asymptotically stable. For local stability, note that both x and y are positive.

Comment: Did you review [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2839828/finding-lyapunov-function-for-a-stable-equilibruim-of-a-non-linear-system/2840558#2840558) and the associated hint in the comments?

Comment: You're almost there, you just need to analyze the behavior of $\dot V$ near $(u, v) = (0, 0)$. For $a = b  =1$, the leading terms in the expansion of $\dot V$ are $-6 u^2 + 4 u v - 2 v^2$. Since this a negative definite quadratic form, there is a punctured neighborhood of the origin where $\dot V$ is negative.

Comment: Thank you all for your help:)